# Why can't I copy .csv into table in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: sql, postgresql, csv, pgadmin

Have been trying to get my csv into pgadmin, however kept facing this error:

```
ERROR:  invalid input syntax for type timestamp: ""time""  
CONTEXT:  COPY nikon2, line 1, column time: ""time""  
SQL state: 22007
```

csv in in this format

```
"time","TOTAL","POSITIVE","NEGATIVE","NEUTRAL"  
"2020-02-17 00:00","4140","457","680","3003"  
"2020-02-18 00:00","3634","255","499","2880"
```

and I have created a table using this

```
CREATE TABLE file_name (  
time timestamp,  
total integer,  
positive integer,   
negative integer,  
neutral integer);
```

I use Excel on a day to day but am hoping to integrate SQL to my work. Any suggestion on this and nifty tips for using pgadmin will be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The first line is the header, so it must not be imported.

Make sure to specify it before importing:

[image]

PS: `time` is an [SQL reserved keyword](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-keywords-appendix.html) and using one of them as a column name may lead to issues